# How to copy data from csv file to other excel files

Tags: vba, excel

Since I am new to VBA I created a code which can open a .csv file and copy data from .csv to an excel file without opening both.

Actually it works for excel files but When I use a .csv file it displays me an error message "SUBSCRIPT OUT OF RANGE".How do I solve this? Thank You!

```
    Sub Copywb1()
    Dim wkb1 As Workbook
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim wkb2 As Workbook
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Setwkb1 = ThisWorkbook
Setwkb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\AAA.xlsx")
Setwkb1 = Workbooks.Open("C\Reports\BBB.csv")
Setsht1 = wkb1.Sheets("Reports")
Setsht2 = wkb2.Sheets("Fees")

sht1.Range("A1:BM9").Copy
sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wkb2.Close True
wkb1.Close True

  End Sub
```

Comment: A .csv file can only have one "sheet", and it won't be named (.csv != Excel file). Just use `Sheets(1)`. You're also missing the space after `Set`. It should be `Set wkb1`, not `Setwkb1`.

Comment: I just noticed that you are missing spaces after `Set`..

Comment: I would like to thank you Comintern and ashleedawg for helping me.my question is when I use below vba (demo_loadDatafromCSV) it pastes copied data to the the excel which my macro is run.Actualy I need to paste it to another .xlsx file sheet and that excel has multiple sheets but I need to paste to one sheet called (Fees)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example I had that you should able to to adapt to your needs fairly easily:

```
Sub demo_loadDataFromCSV()
    Const csvFile = "x:\mypath\myfile.csv"
    Dim ws As Worksheet, csv As Workbook, cCount As Long, cName As String

    ' Application.ScreenUpdating = False       'keep these commented-out until...
    ' Application.DisplayAlerts = False        ' ...done testing/troubleshooting!

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet          'remember where we parked
    Workbooks.Open csvFile                     'open the csv
    Set csv = ActiveWorkbook                   'create object of csv workbook
    cName = csv.Name                           'get name of csv while its open
    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:B").Copy            'copy columns A and B
    ws.Activate                                'go back to the first sheet
    ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  'paste values
    cCount = Selection.Cells.Count             'count pasted cells
    csv.Close                                  'close CSV

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True           're-enable alerts
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True          'resume screen updates

    MsgBox cCount & " cells were copied from " & cName _
                  & " to " & ws.Parent.Name, vbInformation, "Done"
End Sub
```

---

### More Information:

- MS Docs : [**`Workbooks.Open` Method** (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open)
- MS Docs : [**`Range.PasteSpecial` Method (Excel)** (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial)
- CFO : [**Referring to Other Worksheets or Workbooks in Excel VBA**](http://ww2.cfo.com/spreadsheets/2011/08/referring-to-other-worksheets-or-workbooks-in-an-excel-macro/)
- Code VBA : [**Set `Workbook` variable**](http://codevba.com/excel/set_workbook.htm)

Comment: I would like to thank you Comintern and ashleedawg for helping me.my question is when I use below vba (demo_loadDatafromCSV) it pastes copied data to the the excel which my macro is run.Actualy I need to paste it to another .xlsx file sheet and that excel has multiple sheets but I need to paste to one sheet called (Fees) .How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the minor changes in code, now it will select the new workbook and paste the data in the selected sheet.

```
Sub demo_loadDataFromCSV()
Const csvFile = "C:\Users\PC\Downloads\R1C2.txt"
Dim ws As Worksheet, csv As Workbook, cCount As Long, cName As String
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

' Application.ScreenUpdating = False       'keep these commented-out until...
' Application.DisplayAlerts = False        ' ...done testing/troubleshooting!

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet          'remember where we parked
Workbooks.Open csvFile                     'open the csv
Set csv = ActiveWorkbook                   'create object of csv workbook

'to open new workbook
Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse for workbook")

cName = csv.Name                           'get name of csv while its open
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:B").Copy            'copy columns A and B

'Open workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename
'Go to sheets Fees
Set test = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fees")
test.Activate
test.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  'paste values
cCount = Selection.Cells.Count             'count pasted cells
csv.Close                                  'close CSV

Application.DisplayAlerts = True           're-enable alerts
Application.ScreenUpdating = True          'resume screen updates

MsgBox cCount & " cells were copied from " & cName _
              & " to " & ws.Parent.Name, vbInformation, "Done"
End Sub
```